# Using 'card-deck' class, the top and bottom cards coincide

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I'm working using the `card-deck` class on `bootstrap 4.5.0`, the problem I'm facing is that when new cards appear below the previous card, they coincide without delimiter.

**Code**:

```html
<!Doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <title>Index</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="h3">Index page</div>  
      
      <div class="card-deck">
        <div class="card bg-light" style="min-width: 15rem; max-width: 15rem; cursor: pointer;">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">product name</h5>
            <h6 class="card-subtitle">$10</h6>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card bg-light" style="min-width: 15rem; max-width: 15rem; cursor: pointer;">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">product name</h5>
            <h6 class="card-subtitle">$10</h6>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card bg-light" style="min-width: 15rem; max-width: 15rem; cursor: pointer;">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">product name</h5>
            <h6 class="card-subtitle">$10</h6>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card bg-light" style="min-width: 15rem; max-width: 15rem; cursor: pointer;">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">product name</h5>
            <h6 class="card-subtitle">$10</h6>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card bg-light" style="min-width: 15rem; max-width: 15rem; cursor: pointer;">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">product name</h5>
            <h6 class="card-subtitle">$10</h6>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>    
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Expected**:

```
-----  -----  -----  -----
  1      2      3      4
-----  -----  -----  -----
delimiter here
-----
  5
-----
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: What do you mean by delimeter? And can you show how it is now?

Comment: I have created demo here with your code: https://jsfiddle.net/2k41f597

Comment: Hi @Pritesh thanks it worked as expected, if you post as answer sure I'll mark accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created demo here with your code: [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/2k41f597)

```
<!Doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <title>Index</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="h3">Index page</div>  
      
      <div class="card-deck">
        <div class="card bg-light" style="margin-bottom: 10px; min-width: 15rem; max-width: 15rem; cursor: pointer;">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">product name</h5>
            <h6 class="card-subtitle">$10</h6>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card bg-light" style="margin-bottom: 10px; min-width: 15rem; max-width: 15rem; cursor: pointer;">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">product name</h5>
            <h6 class="card-subtitle">$10</h6>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card bg-light" style="margin-bottom: 10px; min-width: 15rem; max-width: 15rem; cursor: pointer;">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">product name</h5>
            <h6 class="card-subtitle">$10</h6>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card bg-light" style="margin-bottom: 10px; min-width: 15rem; max-width: 15rem; cursor: pointer;">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">product name</h5>
            <h6 class="card-subtitle">$10</h6>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card bg-light" style="margin-bottom: 10px; min-width: 15rem; max-width: 15rem; cursor: pointer;">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">product name</h5>
            <h6 class="card-subtitle">$10</h6>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>    
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```